# Why is my MD5 implementation 35% slower than the md-5 crate?

Tags: rust

I wrote a [minimal implementation of the MD5 algorithm](https://github.com/listerone255/md5_speed). Comparing to the [established MD5 crate](https://crates.io/crates/md-5), the crate has a 35% better throughput than mine. I'd like to know why.

In reviewing the crate's code ([relevant section here](https://docs.rs/crate/md-5/0.8.0/source/src/utils.rs)), I see that it essentially does the same thing as I do. I don't see anything algorithm differences. I've avoided bounds checking. I've unrolled the loop. I've inlined calculations.

Running flamegraph on both algorithms, I see that essentially *all* time is spend in the iteration loop. Just that the crate's runs 35% faster (crate on left, mine on right):

[image]

Running criterion gave me the 35% difference:

```
MD5 comparison/mine     time:   [146.02 us 146.87 us 147.79 us]
                        thrpt:  [422.91 MiB/s 425.54 MiB/s 428.02 MiB/s]

MD5 comparison/crate    time:   [107.65 us 108.28 us 109.01 us]
                        thrpt:  [573.34 MiB/s 577.22 MiB/s 580.60 MiB/s]
```

That's 577 MB/s vs 425 MB/s.

Here is my code ([project here](https://github.com/listerone255/md5_speed)). To those familiar with the MD5 algorithm, can you comment on what could be causing the 35% performance difference?

```rust
#![allow(clippy::unreadable_literal)]

fn blockify(inp: &[u8], oup: &mut [u32; 16]) {
    use std::convert::TryInto;
    let inp = &inp[0..64]; // Avoid bounds checking
    *oup = [
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[0..4].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[4..8].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[8..12].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[12..16].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[16..20].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[20..24].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[24..28].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[28..32].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[32..36].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[36..40].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[40..44].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[44..48].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[48..52].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[52..56].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[56..60].try_into().unwrap()),
        u32::from_le_bytes(inp[60..64].try_into().unwrap()),
    ]
}

#[allow(clippy::cognitive_complexity)]
fn iteration(hs: &mut [u32; 4], xs: &[u8]) {
    macro_rules! round_a {
        ($ms:expr, $i:expr, $a:expr, $b:expr, $c:expr, $d:expr, $k:expr, $g:expr, $s:expr) => {{
            unsafe {
                $a = (($b & $c) | (!$b & $d))
                    .wrapping_add($a)
                    .wrapping_add($k)
                    .wrapping_add(*$ms.get_unchecked($g))
                    .rotate_left($s)
                    .wrapping_add($b);
            }
            // println!("{:02}: {:08x} {:08x} {:08x} {:08x}", $i, $a, $b, $c, $d);
        }};
    }
    macro_rules! round_b {
        ($ms:expr, $i:expr, $a:expr, $b:expr, $c:expr, $d:expr, $k:expr, $g:expr, $s:expr) => {{
            unsafe {
                $a = (($d & $b) | (!$d & $c))
                    .wrapping_add($a)
                    .wrapping_add($k)
                    .wrapping_add(*$ms.get_unchecked($g))
                    .rotate_left($s)
                    .wrapping_add($b);
            }
            // println!("{:02}: {:08x} {:08x} {:08x} {:08x}", $i, $a, $b, $c, $d);
        }};
    }
    macro_rules! round_c {
        ($ms:expr, $i:expr, $a:expr, $b:expr, $c:expr, $d:expr, $k:expr, $g:expr, $s:expr) => {{
            unsafe {
                $a = ($b ^ $c ^ $d)
                    .wrapping_add($a)
                    .wrapping_add($k)
                    .wrapping_add(*$ms.get_unchecked($g))
                    .rotate_left($s)
                    .wrapping_add($b);
            }
            // println!("{:02}: {:08x} {:08x} {:08x} {:08x}", $i, $a, $b, $c, $d);
        }};
    }
    macro_rules! round_d {
        ($ms:expr, $i:expr, $a:expr, $b:expr, $c:expr, $d:expr, $k:expr, $g:expr, $s:expr) => {{
            unsafe {
                $a = ($c ^ ($b | !$d))
                    .wrapping_add($a)
                    .wrapping_add($k)
                    .wrapping_add(*$ms.get_unchecked($g))
                    .rotate_left($s)
                    .wrapping_add($b);
            }
            // println!("{:02}: {:08x} {:08x} {:08x} {:08x}", $i, $a, $b, $c, $d);
        }};
    }

    let mut ms = [0; 16];
    blockify(xs, &mut ms);

    let mut r0 = hs[0];
    let mut r1 = hs[1];
    let mut r2 = hs[2];
    let mut r3 = hs[3];

    round_a!(ms, 0, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0xd76aa478, 0, 7);
    round_a!(ms, 1, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0xe8c7b756, 1, 12);
    round_a!(ms, 2, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0x242070db, 2, 17);
    round_a!(ms, 3, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0xc1bdceee, 3, 22);

    round_a!(ms, 4, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0xf57c0faf, 4, 7);
    round_a!(ms, 5, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0x4787c62a, 5, 12);
    round_a!(ms, 6, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0xa8304613, 6, 17);
    round_a!(ms, 7, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0xfd469501, 7, 22);

    round_a!(ms, 8, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0x698098d8, 8, 7);
    round_a!(ms, 9, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0x8b44f7af, 9, 12);
    round_a!(ms, 10, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0xffff5bb1, 10, 17);
    round_a!(ms, 11, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0x895cd7be, 11, 22);

    round_a!(ms, 12, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0x6b901122, 12, 7);
    round_a!(ms, 13, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0xfd987193, 13, 12);
    round_a!(ms, 14, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0xa679438e, 14, 17);
    round_a!(ms, 15, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0x49b40821, 15, 22);

    round_b!(ms, 16, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0xf61e2562, 1, 5);
    round_b!(ms, 17, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0xc040b340, 6, 9);
    round_b!(ms, 18, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0x265e5a51, 11, 14);
    round_b!(ms, 19, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0xe9b6c7aa, 0, 20);

    round_b!(ms, 20, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0xd62f105d, 5, 5);
    round_b!(ms, 21, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0x02441453, 10, 9);
    round_b!(ms, 22, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0xd8a1e681, 15, 14);
    round_b!(ms, 23, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0xe7d3fbc8, 4, 20);

    round_b!(ms, 24, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0x21e1cde6, 9, 5);
    round_b!(ms, 25, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0xc33707d6, 14, 9);
    round_b!(ms, 26, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0xf4d50d87, 3, 14);
    round_b!(ms, 27, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0x455a14ed, 8, 20);

    round_b!(ms, 28, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0xa9e3e905, 13, 5);
    round_b!(ms, 29, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0xfcefa3f8, 2, 9);
    round_b!(ms, 30, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0x676f02d9, 7, 14);
    round_b!(ms, 31, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0x8d2a4c8a, 12, 20);

    round_c!(ms, 32, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0xfffa3942, 5, 4);
    round_c!(ms, 33, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0x8771f681, 8, 11);
    round_c!(ms, 34, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0x6d9d6122, 11, 16);
    round_c!(ms, 35, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0xfde5380c, 14, 23);

    round_c!(ms, 36, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0xa4beea44, 1, 4);
    round_c!(ms, 37, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0x4bdecfa9, 4, 11);
    round_c!(ms, 38, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0xf6bb4b60, 7, 16);
    round_c!(ms, 39, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0xbebfbc70, 10, 23);

    round_c!(ms, 40, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0x289b7ec6, 13, 4);
    round_c!(ms, 41, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0xeaa127fa, 0, 11);
    round_c!(ms, 42, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0xd4ef3085, 3, 16);
    round_c!(ms, 43, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0x04881d05, 6, 23);

    round_c!(ms, 44, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0xd9d4d039, 9, 4);
    round_c!(ms, 45, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0xe6db99e5, 12, 11);
    round_c!(ms, 46, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0x1fa27cf8, 15, 16);
    round_c!(ms, 47, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0xc4ac5665, 2, 23);

    round_d!(ms, 48, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0xf4292244, 0, 6);
    round_d!(ms, 49, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0x432aff97, 7, 10);
    round_d!(ms, 50, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0xab9423a7, 14, 15);
    round_d!(ms, 51, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0xfc93a039, 5, 21);

    round_d!(ms, 52, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0x655b59c3, 12, 6);
    round_d!(ms, 53, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0x8f0ccc92, 3, 10);
    round_d!(ms, 54, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0xffeff47d, 10, 15);
    round_d!(ms, 55, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0x85845dd1, 1, 21);

    round_d!(ms, 56, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0x6fa87e4f, 8, 6);
    round_d!(ms, 57, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0xfe2ce6e0, 15, 10);
    round_d!(ms, 58, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0xa3014314, 6, 15);
    round_d!(ms, 59, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0x4e0811a1, 13, 21);

    round_d!(ms, 60, r0, r1, r2, r3, 0xf7537e82, 4, 6);
    round_d!(ms, 61, r3, r0, r1, r2, 0xbd3af235, 11, 10);
    round_d!(ms, 62, r2, r3, r0, r1, 0x2ad7d2bb, 2, 15);
    round_d!(ms, 63, r1, r2, r3, r0, 0xeb86d391, 9, 21);

    *hs = [
        hs[0].wrapping_add(r0),
        hs[1].wrapping_add(r1),
        hs[2].wrapping_add(r2),
        hs[3].wrapping_add(r3),
    ];
}

pub fn md5(input: &[u8]) -> String {
    let mut hs = [0x67452301, 0xefcdab89, 0x98badcfe, 0x10325476];

    let mut iter = input.chunks_exact(64);
    for chunk in &mut iter {
        iteration(&mut hs, &chunk);
    }

    let mut buf = [0; 64];
    buf[0] = 128;
    buf[56..64].copy_from_slice(&((input.len() * 8) as u64).to_le_bytes());
    iteration(&mut hs, &buf);

    // format!(
    //     "{:08x}{:08x}{:08x}{:08x}",
    //     hs[0].swap_bytes(),
    //     hs[1].swap_bytes(),
    //     hs[2].swap_bytes(),
    //     hs[3].swap_bytes()
    // )
    String::new() // Avoid format! for benchmarking
}
```

---

As an aside, because it has been suspected that the `blockify` function is the bottleneck, I note that I have already tried inlining `unsafe { &*(inp.as_ptr() as *const [u32; 16]) }` to directly convert `&[u8]` to `&[u32;16]` without creating a new array. This is highly non-portable, but regardless made no difference whatsoever to the performance.

Comment: FYI, when I say _minimal_, I mean that it only deals with input that is multiples of 64 bytes in size. I have not implemented block buffering.

Comment: Not entirely sure this has anything to do with MD5 itself, as it looks like the reference implementation is designed to take advantage of inlining, for example. Yours explicitly prevents this due to your choice of code structure.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld How does mine prevent inlining? I've actually inlined all the calculations via macros. How does the crate take advantage of inlining?

Comment: So did the [reference crate](https://docs.rs/crate/md-5/0.8.0/source/src/utils.rs), and your macros work out to pretty much the same thing after expansion. However, their variant is more efficient on the block generation **and** allows them to inline the *entire* function, whereas yours does not. I strongly suspect this is where the performance loss is coming from. On top of that, their block layout is, frankly, better due to their assumption that the original variables *are* defined, something you cannot do (and therefore have a `get_unchecked` call at every round)

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Block generation is not significant. I've separately tested this. Even with `unsafe { &*(xs.as_ptr() as *const [u32; 16]) }` to convert the block without actually generating it, the throughput is the same.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld And I don't understand what you mean by block layout. Please elaborate by pointing out the code.

Comment: It’s got nothing to do with inlining as the comments incorrectly point out. The crate uses md5_asm when compiling on x64 and x86, which implements the loop in assembly, optimizing register pressure.

Comment: @OneTwoMany, that appears to only be the case if you turn on the asm feature.

Answer (score 2):

After some experimentation, the issue does not appear to be your code.

In fact, if you copy the MD5 implementation from the other crate into your crate that copy will still run slower than the version in the other crate. Instead, it runs about the same speed as your code.

I'm not sure what's going on, but it probably has to do with the limitations of optimizations crossing a crate boundary. Probably, some optimization that the rust compiler thinks is a good idea actually degrades performance and this optimization happens to not be possible if the code is split into two crates.